# Passing GPS LonLat to GPS application in mobile after clicking button in Adobe Flash

Tags: google-maps, flash, gps

I would like to ask anyone who can help me. I need to develop a simple application using Adobe Flash and Actionscript3. I don't know how can i link my button (Get Direction button) which is when user click on that button, it will open a location on GPS application on mobile. So user can get direction to go to the location. OR when user click on that button, it can link to google maps. i want to pass that location longitude and latitude to the google maps or GPS application. I really dont get any idea how to solve this. i've looked at many tutorial but still i don't get it.

Someone please help me... tqvm

Comment: The Maps API for Flash was officially deprecated in 2011.
You need to request the key here https://flash-maps-key-request.appspot.com/.

Comment: also https://developer.mapquest.com/ provide an api for flash, check it out~